Final Three Plagues
The last three plagues in Egypt are obviously unique compared to the previous 7. Not just in scope, but all 3 are in darkness. I’m curious if these have any special status in Jewish Theology?
Personally, I’m inclined to view these as a foreshadowing of the End Times.
I also see the last three plagues as the plague of Cain, Abel, and Seth respectively.
Cain was cursed so that the earth would no longer give its strength to him: locusts come and eat everything.
Abel was righteous and favored by the Lord: God casts a great darkness over all of Egypt - only the land of Goshen had light.
Seth is said to have been given to Adam and Eve in place of Abel after Cain slew him: God’s judgment passes over Israel when the Destroyer sees the blood of the slain lambs and goats; the death of the animals taking the place of that of Israel’s firstborn.
Incidentally, the 7th plague seems tied to the Sabbath. For the ones who were spared were those who sheltered, while those who continued working outside as usual were those struck down by the hail storm.


I’m curious if these have any special status in Jewish Theology?

Tradition groups the plagues in 3s, with the 10th standing on its own (Malbim Shemot 7:14), although with regards to some concepts, the last four are grouped together, e.g. they came from the sky and were performed by Hashem Himself (Rashbam's Haggada, although there are several conflicting opinions on this). The plagues are grouped in many different ways generally, but the last 3 before the death of the firstborn are representative of Hashem's power over all powers (the first three attested to His existence, and the second 3 His authority (Malbim ibid; Haggada of the Ritva).
I am unaware of any connection between the plagues and the End Times, especially in the sense that you are asking, and the ideas you have come up with (and generally, site policy considers asking about self-made theories controversial; also note that we still have access to the teachings and explanations given to us by God at Sinai, so it's not common place to come up with self-made theories in the way you are doing). However, the preparation for the 10th plague, as well as the nature of the plagues being both miraculous and within nature (as is specifically explained regarding the plague of Darkness in Likkutei Sichot 31 p.46) are connected to the End Times.
With regards to the former, the circumcision and the Pascal lamb were both physical acts that reveal God's Essence in even the lowest levels of existence and life. This is meant to imbibe the Israelites with a faith that doesn't remain lofty and blind, but permeates their intellect. This allows the faith to flow to their hearts and deeds in an internal, authentic way that encompasses their entire being; their entire soul and body:

The power to descend and affect such lowly levels of existence comes
from a very lofty plane. Accordingly, we can appreciate that the power
of the mitzvah of circumcision - which reveals Godliness within our
physical flesh (even with the organ associated with "yesod, the end of
the torso") - is very great. Based on that logic, the power of the
Pesach sacrifice is even greater, for it draws Godliness into a realm
outside of the human sphere, into one's portion of the world...
... It is written (Michah 7:15) "As in the days of your Exodus from Egypt, I will show [the people] wonders", indicating that the future Redemption will follow the patter of the Exodus from Egypt. The Exodus from Egypt came about in the mert of the Jews' faith, and because of the expression of that faith within their conscious powers - to the extent that encompassed the lowest levels with their personalities (as reflected by circuscision), and even entities entirely outside the human sphere (as reflected by eating the Pesach sacrifice.
Similarly, the future Redemption will also come about in the mertif of faith. Despite the overwhelming concealment of Godliness in the present exile, it is possible to arouse simple faith in how close we are to the coming of Mashiach. "He is standing behind our wall" (Song of Songs 2:9) - i.e. Mashiach is fast approaching; he is eagerly waiting to come.
The intent is that this faith should not remain merely an encompassing potential, but that it should permeate a person's character, beginning with his intellect and emotions and continuing until it affects even his lowest potentials (as alluded to by circumcision).
This is accomplished by studying Chassidus and comprehending them thoroughly. Their study revealse the power of faith and internalizes it within the intellect, enabling it to affect all other potentials, thus causing a change in one's emotional characteristics. [Source. Translated by Sichot in English)

As is noted in Derech Mitzvotecha Haamanat Elokut 1 and 2, faith that has not permeated one's intellect will not have any affect on one's emotions or actions. A person may act according to his faith, but it will be rote and can lead to contradictions, such as a thief praying for success in his theft. It must also be accompanied by knowledge - deep, intimate, inner knowledge, and this is how God's desire and ultimate cosmic plan of dwelling in the lowest world is achieved.
On the latter, the plague of darkness was accompanied by both a miracle, and a natural circumstance. The miracle was the darkness that paralyzed the Egyptians. The natural circumstance was the light that the Jews were able to see with, in order to perform their mission. This will be the same in the times of Mashiach. The Jews will receive miraculous assistance in order to break down any barriers that hinder their Divine service. The Divine service itself though, will take place in a natural, down to earth manner as the mission is, as stated above, to make this lowest world holy - a dwelling for the Almighty - which is the unique mission statement of the Jewish people and religion.
